# High CPU load since 22.04 upgrade

Tags: gnome, video, 22.04, cpu, kodi

Since my upgrade to 22.04 last week my CPU usage is high in idle mode, but as soon as I play a video it's skyrocketing to almost 100% which makes playing video hard. I play my videos using KODI, as I do for years with the same hardware without any issues.
KODI also crashes sometimes, when I start playing a video. When I run "top" gnome-shell is the biggest user of the resources, together with KODI. But when I stop playing the video KODI isn't consuming at all, just 3-8%, gnome still running on high percentages. when I also shutdown KODI, resources all fine again. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: One addition, rebooting does help for a little while, but gnome is using more and more until the buffering issues

Comment: And upgrade from what exactly? Or is it a fresh installation?

Comment: From 20.0.4. I managed to solve it by installing the proprietary Nvidia driver. After upgrade only the opensource one was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the Nvidia driver solved it

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1245057)

Comment: @TejasLotlikar: But, it's the answer to solve the problem